A Gunicorn + Flask + Nginx Application including Apscheduler blocks a new worker pid in Python application once in a while
While apscheduler scheduler service is running in parent PID meanwhile a new "Worker is booting up" after which, requests from nginx lands on this new pid (worker) and gets blocked it does not process it and each thread of this worker picks new request and gets blocked. other request coming to this pid is in waiting and eventually getting timed out with upstream time out.
I tried to debug and reproduce but could not as it occurs suddenly and then I have to kill this worker pid and then no more errors.
Can anyone help me figure out how we can find the lock or why pid is geting blocked.
We use a lot of in-memory caching which apscheduler populates from Database.
I tried to debug but the pid is blocked and has no errors. the pid stays active with increasing cpu up time until killed. It accumulates request upto max-requests and lead to upstream time out. This does not happens during start up of application.
